# What is clone in owl carousel? How can we control the dot numbers in Owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I have been using owl carousel for my website which I saw in one of the commercial websites. The code is as belo

HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel-hp owl-carousel owl-theme">

<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>     
<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div>            

 </div>
```

JS Code

```
 $('.owl-carousel-hp').owlCarousel({
        responsiveClass:true,
        loop:true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        responsive:{
          320:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
          },
          480:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
          },
          667:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
          },
          768:{
            items:4,
            nav:false,
            dots:false
          },
          1024:{
            items:4,
            nav:false,
            dots:false
          }
        }
      });
```

In the 8 items show in HTML, I will be displaying 4 items, that is only 4 items will be in active state. And other 4 should be in cloned state, i.e. owl-item cloned. How to achieve this cloned state? And is there any way that I can show only number of navigation dots based on active item numbers? If the active items are 4, I need to display only 4 dots.

I could not get much documentation on this plugin,  if anyone can answer above question or provide a relevant link, it would be helpful

Comment: Many slider scripts use “cloned” elements so that they can scroll “endlessly”; but they usually take care of creating those cloned elements themselves, you should not need to interfere with that in the first place.